# Iptables bad argument

Tags: networking, bash, iptables, firewall

I'm writing an iptables Bash script, and I can't figure out why I get the below error:

**Variables**

```
iptables=/sbin/iptables
internet_int=ens33
lan_int=ens37
lan_addr=172.16.30.0/24
```

**Rule**

```
#lan -> internet HTTP (80/tcp)
$iptables -A FORWARD -p TCP -i $lan_int -s $lan_addr --sport 1024:65535 -o $internet_int -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

**Problem**

```
Bad argument `172.16.30.0/24'
```

Comment: That exact command works fine for me.

Comment: I get this:
root@fw:/home/toor# bash ipt.template start
Starting Firewall...
Bad argument '172.16.30.0/24'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: i don't know what to say. The syntax looks correct, and indeed works for me.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is line termination. Could there be a carriage return and line feed character at the end of the line (dos type) instead of just unix type line termination, line feed?

Comment: Nope, double checked it...

Comment: Version of iptables ? (iptables --version)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with a iptables-cmd of my own. I put the variables into parantheses which resovled the issue. Maybe it works for your command too:

```
"$iptables" -A FORWARD -p TCP -i "$lan_int" -s "$lan_addr" --sport 1024:65535 -o "$internet_int" -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Haven't tested your command. I assume only the parantheses before the `-s` argument are required. Maybe give it a try.